# How To Change Grid Opacity using Slider Value In C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

I want to change or control grid or something like image or any opacity using slider value.
I got full window control program but I failed to change grid opacity.

**See this code for changing window opacity.**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AllowsTransparency = true;
        }

        private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            this.Opacity = slider.Value / 100;

        }
}
```

And see result:
[Its worked perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGa8.png)

But I want to change grid (image/rectangle or something) opacity via slider value.
I also tried by this code but not working:

```
 private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
                {              
                  mygrid.Opacity =slider.Value / 100;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using binding is a better way and it works! Try to avoid code behind anywhere it's possible.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="{Binding Value, ElementName=mySlider}"/>
    <Slider Name="mySlider" Grid.Row="1" Maximum="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: WOW, That great!
Thanks a lot buddy.